# Issue with Microsoft excel XLSM

Tags: excel, xlsm

I have created an XLSM file which captures data from another Excel file and does some calculation. It works on my machine but if I send the XLSM to other's it doesn't work. 
Also recently I had to re-install OS and Office (same version as earlier), and now the XLSM is not working on my machine also. Is it related to some security issues? All the machines I tried running the XLSM has **same** OS and **same** Office version as all machine are in same organization. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I think your problem is based on static references, if it is I add an answer for more details ;).

Answer (score 0):

When you captures data from another Excel to your own file, your reference will be static like `[C:\users\..\Desktop\someexcel.xlsx]`. this static references will not found on another machine or after changing operating system.

If you want a static reference move other Excel file to somewhere like `[C:\someexcel.xlsx]` and notify other users to copy `someexcel.xlsx` file in their `C:\` root.